# SOQL - How to get the ParentContentFolderId by querying ContentDocument

Tags: soql, content, contentdocument

Recently I have been working a lot in content management system. I have 2 standard objects- contentDocument and contentfolderitem. I assumed the contentfolderItem as master and contentDocument as detail object. The Id of the contentfolderItem is actually the Id in contentdocument when the contentfolderitem is actually a file.

I need to get the contentsize in contentdocument object and ParentContentFolderId in contentfolderitem in single soql query. Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Please check ContentVersion object,
[https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentversion.htm]
. That is where the document size and location is stored.